# Send Data with OnChange on Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I want to send select box value to my NodeJS server with **onchange()** function using **socket.io**.

Now, I can send with button as below codes show;

*server.js;*

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('socketdeneme', function(msg) {
    console.log("Message received: " + msg);
  });
});

http.listen(2000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:2000');
});
```

*index.html;*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var socket = io();

      $('form').submit(function() {
        socket.emit('socketdeneme', $('#m').val());    
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <select id=m multiple>
      <option value="dnm">dnm</option>
      <option value="dnm1">dnm1</option>
      <option value="dnm2">dnm2</option>
    </select>
    <button>Send</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

On the other hand, below code send data with **onchange()** function but I couldn't use it with **socket.io**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitformfabrika() {
          document.formsubmitfabrika.submit();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .change method (https://api.jquery.com/change/) to emit your socketdeneme event which will be received by the server.

Replace

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  socket.emit('socketdeneme', $('#m').val());    
});
```

with

```
$('form').change(function() {
     socket.emit('socketdeneme', $('#m').val());    
});
```